# Out of sample prediction with SARIMAX

Tags: python, statsmodels, predict, sarimax

I am building a seasonal ARIMA model using the `SARIMAX` package from `statsmodels`. The following is an illustration of the model:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX

date_range = pd.date_range(start='2000-01-01', end='2009-12-01', freq='MS')
values = np.random.rand(len(date_range))

ts_full = pd.Series(values, index=date_range)
train = ts_full[:-12]

mdl = SARIMAX(train, order=(1, 0, 0), seasonal_order=(1, 0, 0, 12)).fit()
```

Now I want to see how the model performs on the 12 months of data, which it was not trained on, without refitting the model every month. I tried the following:

```
mdl.predict(ts_full)
```

Which results in the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert input [2000-01-01    0.509615
2000-02-01    0.094391
2000-03-01    0.454202
2000-04-01    0.489502
.
.
.
2009-10-01    0.167847
2009-11-01    0.625154
2009-12-01    0.621803
Freq: MS, dtype: float64] of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> to Timestamp
```

I found several prediction examples online, however they all either predict only 1 period ahead or require that the model be refit every time period before making the forecast. Is there any way to make the prediction using data on which the model was not trained?

Comment: Did you read about dynamic predictions [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_sarimax_stata.html)?

Comment: Dynamic predictions do not address the problem described here.

Comment: Can you explain why?  From that site "One-step-ahead prediction uses the true values of the endogenous values at each step to predict the next in-sample value. Dynamic predictions use one-step-ahead prediction up to some point in the dataset (specified by the dynamic argument); after that, the previous predicted endogenous values are used in place of the true endogenous values for each new predicted element."  That sounds like what you want to me.

Comment: If I call ```mdl.predict()``` it will generate prediction based on all the values in my training data. The dynamic options simply tells it to not use all the data but only up to some point in time and after that use the predicted values instead of the real ones in order to forecast after that point. In my example I need to train the model on one dataset and the apply it to another.

Comment: So the 12 months of data that you want to evaluate the model on isn't the 12 months after the training data, but rather some completely unrelated dataset?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I solved it by using SARIMAXResults.apply (https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAXResults.apply.html#statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAXResults.apply). It applies the fit results to new data. To make a new prediction pased on new data, I use the original fit results `results` like in the following.

```
resultsRestricted = results.apply(actual, exog=X, refit=False)
pred = resultsRestricted.get_prediction(start=pd.to_datetime('2013-12-01'),
  end = pd.to_datetime('2013-12-01'), 
  exog = futureX)
```